# Why I cannot remove a view from another controller?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, xib

In my ViewController's Storyboard I added a UIView and on click on the button I change its alpha from 0.0 -> 1.0:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: {
        self.blurView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.blurView.addSubview(self.signUpView)
    })
```

where `signUpView` is a XIB, with the next code:

```
class func signUpView() -> UIView {
    return UINib(nibName: "SignUpView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
}
```

Now, I want to on click on the button on my XIB, to remove my `blurView`. For this I do:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.1, options: [.CurveEaseOut], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
            ViewController().blurView!.removeFromSuperview()
        }, completion: { _ in
    })
```

but it returns nothing. When I've tried also to call a ViewController function `removeXIB()`:

```
func removeXIB() {
    self.blurView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

from my SignUpView class, it crashes with the error that `self.blurView` is equal to nil.

How can I fix this problem and remove from my ViewController `blurView` from `SignUpView` XIB class?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewController()` returns you a new instance of `ViewController` class,
It has no initialized `blurView` and `springUpView` (that's why you get a crash, when you try to apply forced unwrapping to `blurView` property value, when it's `nil`).

What you need is a concrete instance of `ViewController` that instantiated your view

By the way that is a bad way to manage views. Your view needs to have some kind of delegate and to ask its delegate to react on user's actions (remove view from superview in your case)

Comment: So, instead of `ViewController().removeXIB()` to use delegates? Yes?

Comment: @JohnDoe instead of ViewController() use a viewController that is instantiated from storyboard. ViewController() is in fact ViewController.init() call, which creates new instance of ViewController class.

Delegation and other things is a question of OOD.

Comment: Did you mean such: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") `?

Comment: Even when I'm using `var v: ViewController! v.blurView.removeFromSuperview()` it returns me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: well, I guess then you need to read more about OOP, swift and iOS Development... that's really hard to proceed doing things when you don't have enough knowledge

Comment: I have enough knowledge, I just did not fully understand you